# Unique field for unique id

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

Houston, we have a problem.

I'm developing a API Rest using mongoose and i need the mongoose don't save POST request's when the unique field value is in there.

Example:

```
{'_id': '1234', 'fieldUnique': 'fieldTeste'} // Allowed.
{'_id': '1234', 'fieldUnique': 'fieldTeste1'} // Allowed.

{'_id': '5678', 'fieldUnique': 'fieldTeste'} // Allowed.
{'_id': '5678', 'fieldUnique': 'fieldTeste1'}// Allowed.

// Imagine mongoose printing: Are you crazy? This exists.
{'_id': '1234', 'fieldUnique': 'fieldTeste'} 

//Imagine Again: I will not repeate. This exists! Get out here.
{'_id':'1234', 'fieldUnique':'fieldTeste1'}
```

Houston. Can you help me with this little problem showing how to make it in mongoose schema or showing the logic in the request?

From Brazil, with love.
Hugo.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking as `_id` must always be unique.

Comment: No, i want the field "fieldUnique" must be unique for this _id

Comment: That doesn't make any sense as you can only have one document with a given `_id`.

Comment: This is just one example. My real field in my project is called 'TAG' when ''TAG'' must be unique for my another field called ''prop'' in my collection. Could i make this logic in MongoDB?

Comment: It's like: If TAG exists in prop, i don't save the document.

Comment: Awesome, i will see this post. Thank you Johnny!